# How to represent the solution of $z^{2}+2z+5=0$ in in Euler form?

Tags: complex-numbers

I get the solution of  $z^{2}+2z+5=0$

$z=-1+2i \;\;
\overline {z}=-1-2i$

Comment: Added a little to your $\LaTeX$ to make things more readable.  Hope you don't mind!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Hint : let $z=a+ib$ then in euler form $z=re^{i\theta }$

where $r=\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$ and $\theta=tan^{-1}({b/a})$

This link  might help http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/Forms.aspx